# Why does modifier order matter in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

When applying modifiers to a view in SwiftUI, it appears that the order matters.

For example, this code:

```swift
HStack {
  Text("Hello world")
    .padding()
    .background(Color(UIColor.darkGray))
    .cornerRadius(20.0)
}
```

..will produce this:

[image: watchOS preview displaying a simple view]

Change the order of the modifiers and things change. This code effectively 'breaks' the modifiers, as padding and corner radius are no longer applied:

```swift
HStack {
  Text("Hello world")
    .background(Color(UIColor.darkGray))
    .padding()
    .cornerRadius(20.0)
}
```

[image: watchOS preview displaying a simple view where the view modifiers aren't applied]

Why is this? I'm sure there's a logical explanation but I couldn't find any documentation or rationale for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modifier is function that returns `some View` by wrapping the content View it modifies. For example `.padding` returns `some View` that implements a padding functionality and its content is the View it modifies, plus the padding:

So, conceptually:

```
HStack {
  Text("Hello world")
    .padding()
    .background(Color(UIColor.darkGray))
    .cornerRadius(20.0)
}
```

is roughly equivalent to (names and params are made up):

```
HStack(content: {
   CornerRadiusView(20.0, content: {
      BackgroundView(Color(UIColor.darkGray), content: {
         PaddingView(content: { 
            Text("Hello world") 
         })
      })
   })
})
```

Hopefully, it's clear from the example how the order of the modifiers changes the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

**New Dev**'s answer is correct. [Here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-modifier-order-matters) is also another good explanation what happens behind the scenes. It's just another point of view of the same concept:

> Whenever we apply a modifier to a SwiftUI view, we actually create a
>   new view with that change applied – we don’t just modify the existing
>   view in place. If you think about it, this behavior makes sense – our
>   views only hold the exact properties we give them, so if we set the
>   background color or font size there is no place to store that data.